# Continue persisting entities after the UniqueConstraintViolationException in Doctrine ORM?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to continue persisting entities after an UniqueConstraintViolationException

I'm uploading a list of codes and saving into the database using Doctrine ORM entities.

I want to avoid the duplicated codes and continue saving the others.

The simple solution of querying first to see if the code is in the database and then save is okay but it is posible just to ignore the exception and continue? To avoid query the database.

```
foreach($uploadEntities as $entity){ 
 try{
   $em->persist($entity);
 }catch(UniqueConstraintViolationException){
   //ignore  
 }
}
```

Comment: Basically no.  Tossing an exception effectively destroys the entity manager.  Just one of those things.  The only way would be to make a brand new entity manager and start over.  Use the validation system to check the uniqueness before trying to persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to catch the exception on the `$em->flush()` call.

Consider that after such an exception the transaction is rolled back and the entity manager gets closed.

You should then reopen it with

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->resetManager();
```

But be aware that as a result of this procedure, all previously managed or removed instances of the EntityManager become detached. The state of the detached objects will be the state at the point at which the transaction was rolled back. The state of the objects is in no way rolled back and thus the objects are now out of synch with the database. The application can continue to use the detached objects, knowing that their state is potentially no longer accurate.

So you should refetch from the dB all the previous fetched objects you need to work on.

It may be convenient to flush every persisted object separately so that you can skip the Bad object and go on.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#exception-handling

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is don't use this type of work-flow, for performance reasons is better check all existent codes in the database and then ignore existent ones.

```
$em->createQueryBuilder()
          ->select('code.code')
          ->from(Code::class, 'code')
          ->where($qb->expr()->in('code.code', $importedCodes));

$existentCodes = array_column($qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult(), 'code');
if (in_array($currentCode, $existentCodes)){
     continue;
}
```

in the other hand can wrap this type of process in a transaction. If you are uploading many many codes, use a batch or anything else to improve the performance.